# C++ function template full specialization error

Tags: c++, templates

I am having this template matching error. I know partial specialization is not allowed in for function template, but I think it should work with full specialization. What change do I need to make to fix this issue ? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void allocate(){
    std::cout << "default" << std::endl;
}

template<>
void allocate<int>() {
    std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
}

template<>
void allocate<double>() {
    std::cout << "double" << std::endl;    
}




int main()
{
    allocate();  // Compiler error, I expect this should match the first template function.
    allocate<int>();
    allocate<double>();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the template argument explicitly, the template parameter `T` can't be deduced from the context. e.g.

```
allocate<void>();
```

Or specify default argument for the template parameter, e.g.

```
template<typename T = void>
void allocate(){
    std::cout << "default" << std::endl;
}
```

then you can call it as

```
allocate(); // T is void
```

Answer (score 0):

The primary template needs the template parameter to be specified explicitly, so you can do:

```
allocate<struct T>();  // ok
```

and since `T` is a new type named only for the purpose of this call, there is guaranteed to not be a specialization for this type, and the primary template will be called.

---

You could also give a default type for the template parameter in the primary:

```
template<typename T = struct Default>
void allocate(){
    std::cout << "default" << std::endl;
}
```

and again, no specialization can exist for `Default` since this type only exists in the scope of the primary template.

Now you can call the primary template without template parameters:

```
allocate();
```